# Build agent no DotNetFramework MSBuild and VSTest capability in Team Foundation Server 2017

Tags: tfs

Since a while I discovered some of my buildagent doesn't have the necessary capabilities anymore to build a .NET Framwork web application. When I installed these build agents a few months ago it worked perfect. For some misterious reasons these capabilities went away. Since a week we have VS2017 installed on that machine. A reboot of the machine where the build agent is running doesn't help. Even we rebooted the Team Foundation Server machine. Can any help me with this problem?

Comment: What's the VS2017 version you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below items to let the agent to identify the capabilities:

- Restart the Agent service to identify the capabilities
- Add User Capabilities manually:

  **Settings** >> **AgentPools** >> Select the pool >> select the specific Agent  >>  **Capabilities** >> **Add capability** under USER CAPABILITIES
- Register capabilities to the machine following below steps, thus all the agents will automatically pick up the capabilities.

  **Control Panel** >> **System** >> **Advanced System Settings** >> **Environment Variables** >> **New** System Variable >> Enter the `variable name` and `value` listed below  >> OK >>

  After doing so, **restart the agents services** will have each of them automatically pick up new capabilities.

Below capabilities for your reference (based on your environment and installed version):

```
DotNetFramework             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework_4.6.1       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework_4.6.1_x64   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

MSBuild           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
MSBuild_15.0      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
MSBuild_15.0_x64  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\

VSTest      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
VSTest_15.0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

VisualStudio          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
VisualStudio_15.0     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
VisualStudio_IDE_15.0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed your step regarding adding the settings as user capalbility. The build agents pick up the build task now. But when the solution was build an error is returned from the build task. Exit code -1073741502 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\AgentV2_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\AgentV2_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\VSBuild.ps1'''))"'.

Comment: What about creating a new build definition? also try using another build agent machine if possible.